Shiny geofencing for Maui on iOS results in a timeout exception
When using Shiny for Maui on iOS I am encountering a problem with geofencing.
When starting a geofence I get no error, and it shows ut in a list when I request all monitores regions,
var allMonitoredRegions= _geofenceManager.GetMonitorRegions()
Although the geofences shows up in this list, the OnStatusChanged method does not trigger when entering or exiting the fence.
Also, while the geofences shows up in the list, when I try to check the status of a region, that is monitored,
var state = await _geofenceManager.RequestState(region);
, this exception occurs:
System.TimeoutException: 'Could not retrieve latest GPS coordinates to be able to determine geofence current state'
This only happens on iOS, on Android it works as expected.
All runtime permissions have been added to the info.plist, as well as the background modes required for location updated.
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Say something useful here that your users will understand</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Say something useful here that your users will understand</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Say something useful here that your users will understand</string>
    

<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>

I have also made sure the UseShiny() had beed added to the MauiProgram, as well as the builder.Services.AddGeofencing<MyGeofenceDelegate>();
I have used the Shiny template to create new projects with the same results, I have checked using different iOS devices, I have made sure all permissions have been enabled, and every time I get the same exception when checking the state of a region for iOS and not on Android.

there is an additional setup in PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file mentioned in https://shinylib.net/client/locations/geofencing/#setup-1 for iOS, you also done this?
